# Ajax dynamically adding textbox is not working in PrimeFaces v3.5

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

My `h:form` contains a `p:selectOneMenu` component, which has two values single and multiple. The `h:form` also contains a default `p:inputText`. My objective is to add multiple `p:inputText` component only when value multiple is selected. Please see the attached screenshot-
[image]

Below is my view, which suppose to send `ajax` request, whenever icon button is clicked-

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel header="Dynamically Add textbox">
        <p:selectOneMenu id="runType" value="#{repeateRun.runType}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{repeateRun.runList}" var="runType" itemLabel="#{runType}" itemValue="#{runType}" />
            <p:ajax update="outPanel" listener="#{repeateRun.renderComponent}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
        <h:panelGrid id="runList">
            <ui:repeat value="#{repeateRun.runs}" var="run">
                <p:inputText value="#{run.runValue}" />
            </ui:repeat>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:outputPanel id="outPanel">
            <p:commandButton update="runList" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add more" rendered="#{repeateRun.showAddButton}">
                <f:ajax render="runList" listener="#{repeateRun.addRun}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:outputPanel>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` RepeateRun is following-

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class RepeateRun implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<String> runList;
    private List<Run> runs;
    private int runValue;
    private String runType;
    private boolean showAddButton = false;
    private static final String SINGLE = "Single";
    private static final String MULTIPLE = "Multiple";
    //Note : Getters Setters are removed while putting here
    @PostConstruct
    public void initBean() {
        this.setRunList(this.populateRunList());
        this.setRuns(this.populateRuns());
    }
    public void addRun() {
        if (this.runs == null) {
            this.setRuns(this.populateRuns());
        } else {
            this.runs.add(this.defaultRun());
        }
    }
    public void renderComponent() {
        if (this.getRunType().equals(SINGLE)) {
            this.setShowAddButton(false);
        } else {
            this.setShowAddButton(true);
        }
    }
    private List<String> populateRunList() {
        List<String> runList = new ArrayList<String>();
        runList.add(SINGLE);
        runList.add(MULTIPLE);
        return runList;
    }
    private Run defaultRun() {
        Run defaultRun = new Run();
        defaultRun.setRunValue(1);
        return defaultRun;
    }
    private List<Run> populateRuns() {
        List<Run> runs = new ArrayList<Run>();
        runs.add(this.defaultRun());
        return runs;
    }
}
```

So after selecting the value Multiple in `f:selectItems` the plus icon button comes but the button is not invoking attached method i.e. `addRun`. To confirm the method `addRun` call after clicking, I put some `sysout` statements in `addRun` method. I saw that `sysout` is not flushed.  At the same time I saw some `xml` response in the firebug.

Where is the problem?

Comment: You forgot to tell what exactly the problem is. What exactly happens (not)?

Comment: Does the addRun ethod execute when clicking on the icon button ?

Comment: @Laabidi: based on the code posted so far, it won't, provided that it's rendered, but the OP wasn't exactly clear on the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC, didn't get your remark, "it won't, provided that it's rendered". I thought, may be, the method runs, but the problem is with the 'render' part, noticing OP is not using prependId="false" in the form

Comment: @Laabidi: `<f:ajax>` don't work in PF components.

Comment: I am very sure, f:ajax works very fine with PF 2.2.1, may be with later versions, things changed. However, I would recommend use of p:ajax

Comment: @BalusC: I apologize. Problem description is appended in the question. Please see the updated question.

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi: The method `addRun` is not getting invoked on click. however each time when i click on the icon, i can see a request in firebug, which is returning some `xml` content.

Comment: @BalusC: I think you are right since `<f:ajax>` is not invoking the method `addRun` on click action. What can be the other way to get the same functionality. I mean I just want to have a `p:inputText` and `p:selectOneMenu` with two values, in which whenever value multiple is selected, the add button should display. So that user can enter multiple values in the `p:inputText`. I think i need to call `addRun` directly from `p:commandButton` in `ajax` way but how?

Comment: would you use p:ajax instead of f:ajax and see what happens ?

Comment: Already did but no change.. `addRun` is not called but i can see a request in firebug

Comment: @BalusC: Any hack? I am unable to get the clue :(

Comment: @BalusC: I found the culprit i.e. `            <p:commandButton update="runList" icon="ui-icon-plusthick"
                title="Add more" rendered="#{!repeateRun.showAddButton}">
                <p:ajax update="runList" listener="#{repeateRun.addRun}" />
            </p:commandButton>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with `f:ajax` which doesn't work with `p:commandButton`. Below are the culprit lines-

```
<p:commandButton update="runList" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add more" rendered="#{repeateRun.showAddButton}">
     <f:ajax render="runList" listener="#{repeateRun.addRun}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

The above lines should be replaced with below line

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{repeateRun.addRun}" update="runList" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" title="Add more" rendered="#{repeateRun.showAddButton}" />
```